# Automatic IPv6 WAN Address Negotiation

Tags: debian, dhcp, ipv6

I'm running vanilla Debian 4.19 as a home router but am having trouble setting up automatic IPv6 address negotiation at boot. I think I have the right settings for the WAN interface (`eno1`) in `sysctl.conf` and `interfaces`:

```
# /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.eno1.accept_ra=2
net.ipv6.conf.eno1.forwarding=0

# /etc/network/interfaces
iface eno1 inet6 auto
  dhcp 1
  request_prefix 1
```

But on reboot, `eno1` is only assigned a v4 global address and a link-local v6 address. Upon running `dhclient` manually, I see that a v6 global address is assigned, however even then there is a concerning warning towards the end:

```
$ sudo dhclient -6 -N -v eno1
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
...
Listening on Socket/eno1
Sending on   Socket/eno1
PRC: Confirming active lease (INIT-REBOOT).
XMT: Forming Confirm, 0 ms elapsed.
XMT:  X-- IA_NA <last4:bytes:of:mac>
XMT:  | X-- Confirm Address 2001:<more:public:digits>
XMT:  V IA_NA appended.
XMT: Confirm on eno1, interval 930ms.
<repeat Forming..Confirm messages x3 with different times>
Max retransmission duration exceeded.
PRC: Bound to lease <14:bytes:in:hex:pairs>.
```

Despite the warning, after running `dhclient` I can successfully `ping6` targets across the internet. I know I could set the command to run as part of `id-up.d`, but I feel like that would be papering over some deeper problem that I don't quite understand.

**Edit:** Looks like I spoke too soon about it "just working" despite the warning. After a few minutes, the v6 address is disassociated from `eno1` and the following messages appear in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 24 16:33:04 citadel dhclient[711]: PRC: Rebinding lease on eno1.
Jun 24 16:33:04 citadel dhclient[711]: XMT: Rebind on eno1, interval 10530ms.
<repeats for a while>
Jun 24 16:45:04 citadel dhclient[711]: PRC: Address 2001:<more:public:digits> depreferred.
Jun 24 16:45:04 citadel dhclient[711]: PRC: Address 2001:<more:public:digits> expired.
Jun 24 16:45:04 citadel dhclient[711]: PRC: Bound lease is devoid of active addresses.  Re-initializing.
Jun 24 16:45:04 citadel dhclient[711]: Cannot renew without an active binding.
Jun 24 16:45:04 citadel dhclient[711]: XMT: Solicit on eno1, interval 1030ms.
<repeats>
```

Comment: Does tcpdump confirm the DHCP server responding to the requests? Do you have any ip6tables or nft rules blocking input packets? (DHCPv4 clients magically bypass iptables due to raw-socket usage, but DHCPv6 clients don't.)

Comment: @user1686 That seems to have solved part of the problem - adding a rule to accept new `--dport 546` connections allows `dhclient` requests to succeed immediately, but the system still doesn't seem to get an address at boot.